# How to map a path suffix to a query parameter using Java Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Background: we have build a RESTful API using Jersey a while ago where we map the uri /items.json to a json array of ids and /items/{id}.json to the json object of a single item. Now we want to create a list with some meta data for each item and would like to use a selector like /items.data.json, similar to apache sling.

So far: I just extended the UriConnegFilter to parse the uri for additional suffixes, something like this:

```
public class UriSelectorFilter extends UriConnegFilter {
protected List<String> selectors; // this list is populated in the constructor

    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        super.filter(request);
        // search for suffix in last path segment, see http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/UriConnegFilter.java?rev=5034

        final String[] suffixes = segment.getPath().split("\\.");
        for (int i = suffixes.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            final String suffix = suffixes[i];
            if(selectors.contains(suffix)) {
                request.getQueryParameters().putSingle("selector", suffix);

                final int index = path.lastIndexOf('.' + suffix);
                path = new StringBuilder(path).delete(index, index + suffix.length() + 1).toString();
                suffixes[i] = "";
            }
        }

        if (length != path.length()) {
            request.setUris(
                    request.getBaseUri(),
                    request.getRequestUriBuilder().replacePath(path).build());
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

This filter works perfect, it finds the selector part of my uri and adds a query param to the request object. But in my Resource I added a @QueryParam attribute, which is only filled with the default value and not the added query value:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getItemsJSON(@DefaultValue("id") @QueryParam("selector") String selector) {
    // query param is not filled with the selector that was found in the UriSelectorFilter
}
```

Does anybody have a suggestion how I can provide my resource with the selector that was detected? Is there a better way than using a QueryParam? (Note: if I add the query to my url like '?selector=something' then the attribute is filled correctly.)

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need another argument that is annotated with `@PathParam`, and you need to specify in your `@Path` annotation (on the method or class) how to bind these bits together. For example, to deal with a path like `/items/foobar42/data.json` you might do this:

```
@GET
@Path("/items/{item}/data.json")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getItemsJSON(@PathParam("item") String itemId,
        @DefaultValue("id") @QueryParam("selector") String selector) {
    // Now you've got an itemId and a possible selector...
}
```

Trying to do all the mapping with a filter… that seems difficult to me given that there's a nice declarative way of doing it instead. You can even specify a regular expression in the `@Path` to allow for matching a more complex variable section; I do that in my own code to create a method that can serve a whole hierarchical filesystem.

(Note that the `{`braced`}` item in the `@Path` should match the name in the `@PathParam` annotation, and you can have multiple items matched from the path if necessary; just use several `@PathParam`-annotated arguments.)